# Validate object/struct without failing

Tags: c#, validation

Assume we have a huge list of numeric cartesian coordinates (5;3)(1;-9) etc. To represent a point in oop I created a struct/object (c#):

```
public struct Point
{
    public int X, Y { get; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        // Check if x,y falls within certain boundaries (ex. -1000, 1000)
    }
}
```

It might be wrong of how I am using struct. I guess normally you would not use a constructor but this is not the point.

Suppose I want to add a list of 1000 points and there is no guarantee that these coordinates fall within boundaries. Simply if the point is not valid, move to the next one without failing and inform user about it. As for object, I would think that Point should be responsible for instantiation and validation by itself but I am not sure how to deal with it in this particular case. Checking x, y beforehand by the caller would be the simplest approach but it does not feel right because caller would have to handle logic that should reside in Point.

What would the most appropriate approach to validate and handle incorrect coordinates without failing and violating SRP?

Comment: [System.Drawing.Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx), no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder `System.Drawing.Point` is a mutable struct. Ugh! It should be hanged to dry and buried as deep as possible ;). Personally, I avoid using `Point` unless the API i'm interacting with forces me to.

Comment: @InBetween Just posted it as an alternative option than re-writing it all over again. But your point is why I commented it and not wrote it up as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in the constructor; the constructor either runs succesfully or it doesn't. If it doesn't its because an exception is raised, so, so much for silently failing. You *could* catch exceptions but that woul basically mean you are using exceptions as a control flow mechanism and that is a big no no, don't do that!

One solution similar to what you are thinking is to use a static factory method:

```
public struct Point
{
    public static bool TryCreatePoint(int x, int y, Bounds bounds, out Point point)
    {
         if (x and y are inside bounds)
         {
             point = new Point(x, y); 
             return true;
         }

         point = default(Point);
         return false;
    }

    //...
}
```

And the code adding points to the list should act based upon creation success.

Fun fact: if you are using C# 7 the code could look a lot cleaner:

```
public static (bool Succesful, Point NewPoint) TryCreatePoint(int x, int y, Bounds bounds)
{
     if (x and y are inside bounds)
         return (true, new Point(x, y));

     return (false, default(Point));
}
```

Comment: Nice usage of C#7-features.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm loving the new features in c# 7. If you've ever dabbed in functional languages, pattern matching and native tuple support is going to be awesome.

Comment: Just for curiosity: how to call that method?

Comment: @HimBromBeere `var result = TryCreatePoint(...)` and it's strongly typed, so you can go ahead and do `if (result.Succesful) { points.Add(result.NewPoint); }`. Nice!

Comment: Incredible, how could I live so long without this feature?!

Comment: @HimBromBeere This is just the tip of the iceberg. Read this short summary about [C# 7 new features](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) or simply download *Visual Stuido 2017 RC* and play with it.

Comment: Quite a discovery for me too. Thanks

Comment: Seeing that the convention for TryDoStuff-methods (e.g. `TryGetValue` on the dictionary) is to return a single bool value and have the retrieved value in an out parameter, I'd recommend to stick to this convention to keep code consistent. Also, you might find your code (as in: your method) cleaner to look at with the tuple type, but I'd argue the tuple return value makes the consuming code less clean, since you can't use the return value directly in any conditional clause.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is simply not posible, an instance of a class is either fully created or not at all. If the constructor has been called the only way to *not* instantiate an instance is by throwing an exception.

So you have these two opportunities to do this:

1. Extract a method `Validate` that returns a bool and can be called from the caller of your class.

   ```
   public struct Point
   {
       public int X, Y { get; }

       public Point(int x, int y)
       {
       }
   }
   public bool Validate() { return -1000 <= X && X <= 1000 && -1000 <= Y and Y <= 1000; }
   ```

   Of course you could do the same using a property.
2. Throw an exception in the constructor

   ```
   public Point(int x, int y)
   {
       if(x > 1000) throw new ArgumentException("Value must be smaller 1000");
       // ...
   }
   ```

However the best solution IMHO is to validate the input before you even think about creating a point, that is check the arguments passed to the constructor beforehand:

```
if(...) 
    p = new Point(x, y);
else 
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three options:

1. Have the constructor throw an exception that you catch. This is not really great if you are expecting a lot of failures.
2. Have an IsValid property on the struct that you can use to filter it out once created.
3. Have the thing loading the data take responsibility for validating the data as well. This would be my preferred option. You say "it does not feel right because caller would have to handle logic that should reside in Point" but I would argue that the responsibility for checking that loaded data is correct is with the thing loading the data, not the data type. You could *also* have it throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException in the constructor if the inputs are not valid now that you are no longer expecting anything invalid to be passed as a belt and bracers approach to things.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, Point shouldn't check boundaries, so the caller should do that. A point is valid in the range that their X and Y can operate (int.MinValue and int.MaxValue). So a -1000000,2000000 is a valid point. The problem is that this point isn't valid for YOUR application, so YOUR application (the caller), the one who is using point, should have that logic, not inside the point constructor.

Comment: IMHO. Well, Point is a custom object that should represent what I want it to. I can say that (5000;5000) is not a Point because it does not correspond to the rules. I would not mix the technical limits of an int with business rules.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but a point is a point, and (5000;5000) is still a valid point. Your rules are business rules, and for me, that shouldn't affect to the Point (as a generic class). What would yo do if you want to reuse the same class (in this case, Point), in another project where the boundaries are different?

Comment: It really depends on given domain rules. If you have a clear statement that a Point by no means can be more than certain value, that is it. It means there is no such case as what if this or that (and this is my case). In other case I would totally agree with you and it might be clarified by introducing a subtype for Point (ex. LimitedPoint).

Comment: Well, yes, but still that Point class can only be used for that project, and could not be used for another scenarios (as Point is a pretty generic class that you will probably want to use it in more than one project and you would like to have it in a library project).
Anways, you got your answer already :). You could throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException or simply add a IsValid property on the class

Comment: Yes, I am just discussing this for my personal interest, you know, sometimes you might find some insights even if it is about different topic :). Anyway thanks for a discussion

Answer (score 0):

Structs in C# are funny so I'll add another "funny" way to check:

```
struct Point
{
    int _x;
    public int X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set { _x = value; ForceValidate(); }
    } // simple getter & setter for X 

    int _y;
    public int Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set { _y = value; ForceValidate(); }
    } // simple getter & setter for Y

    void ForceValidate()
    {
        const MAX = 1000;
        const MIN = -1000;

        if(this.X >= MIN && this.X <= MAX && this.Y >= MIN && this.Y <= MAX)
        {
            return;
        }
        this = default(Point); // Yes you can reasign "this" in structs using C# 
    }
}
```

Comment: WTF?! Unimaginable this actually works. Seems quite ugly to me but does it´s job.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I know it's ugly :D But it makes me laugh whenever i see assignment to `this`.

Comment: You´ve definitly deserved the +1 for this strange C#-feature (and the guys from MS deserve a kick in the ass).